# Make GPU available again after numba.cuda.close()?

Tags: python, pytorch, numba

So when I run `cuda.select_device(0)` and then `cuda.close()`. Pytorch cannot access the GPU again, I know that there is way so that PyTorch can utilize the GPU again without having to restart the kernel. But I forgot how. Does anyone else know?

```
from  numba import cuda as cu
import torch 


# random tensor
a=torch.rand(100,100)

#tensor can be loaded onto the gpu()
a.cuda()

device = cu.get_current_device()
device.reset()

# thows error "RuntimeError: CUDA error: invalid argument"
a.cuda()

cu.close()
# thows error "RuntimeError: CUDA error: invalid argument"
a.cuda()

torch.cuda.is_available()
#True
```

And then trying to run cuda-based pytorch code yields:

```
RuntimeError: CUDA error: invalid argument
```

Comment: is this question about numba or pytorch?

Comment: both I guess because the "reopening" the gou with numba only works for pytorch but not for tensorflow

Comment: Ok so I have tagged this appropriately.

Comment: Can you provide a snippet to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @Janosch Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @Blade no unfortunately not :(

Answer (score 1):

could you provide a more complete snippet, I am running

```
from numba import cuda
import torch 
device = cuda.get_current_device()
device.reset()
cuda.close()
torch.cuda.isavailable()
```

which prints `True`, not sure what is your issue?

Comment: At least in my case, I'm seeing the issue when I try to then do something with torch. Ie - torch.tensor([1,2,3]).cuda() and it will fail to add the new object to the GPU

Comment: I added the torch.tensor line to the snippet and it still works for me. Can you share your snippet so that I can try it?

Comment: Hey I updated the example to demonstrate my problem

Comment: cuda.close() is unrecoverable.. use `device = cuda.get_current_device(); device.reset()`   stackoverflow.com/a/73517694/4240654

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but with TensorFlow and Keras when iterating through a for loop to tune hyperparamenters. It did not free up the GPU memory used by older models. The cuda solution did not work for me. The following did:

```
import gc
gc.collect()
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, I will tryit next time I am running into the issue

Answer (score 0):

This has two possible culprits.

some driver issue be it numba driver or kernel driver managing gpu.
reason for suspecting this is Roger did not see this issue. or such issue is not reported to numba repo.

Another possible issue.
cuda.select_device(0)
which is not needed.
is there any strong reason do use this explicitly ?

Analysis :
do keep in mind design for [`cuda.get_current_device()`](https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/a812eed4dd23aa6ebb4bbea391b63dafdd912832/numba/cuda/api.py#L441)
and [`cuda.close()`](https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/a812eed4dd23aa6ebb4bbea391b63dafdd912832/numba/cuda/api.py#L451)

they are dependent on context and not gpu. as per documentations of get_current_device

> Get current device associated with the current thread

Do check

```
gpus = cuda.list_devices()
```

before and after your code.
if the gpus listed are same.
then you need to create context again.
if creating context agiain is problem.  please attach your complete code and debug log if possible.

Comment: Hey sorry I am not aware of the concept of context. Actually using torch.cuda.is_available() yields True after closing it with cu.close() but I cant load tensors via. cuda()